# rhel + root file-system is filling, despite no large files or directories

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, disk-usage, lsof

I want to share the following strange behavior on our rhel 7.6 server

root file system is almost full ( used 95% ) , when root file system size is 100G

we can see that folders that belong to root file system are not consuming so much

```
0 bin
145M boot
0 dev
50M etc
184K home
0 lib
0 lib64
0 media
0 mnt
698M opt
6.0M root
4.1G run
0 sbin
140K script
0 srv
0 sys
360K tmp
6.5G usr
```

also according to rhel - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

we checked also ( as rhel recommended )

```
lsof / | egrep "deleted|COMMAND"
COMMAND     PID           USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
lsof /var | egrep "deleted|COMMAND"
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
```

but as we see above no entries lines

we also verified by

lsof +L 1

```
# lsof +L 1
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK      NODE NAME
java    44225 yarn 2436r   REG  8,192  1084337     0  99222309 /DB/data1/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/38743643/current/finalized/subdir204/subdir193/blk_15230353883 (deleted)
java    44875 yarn 3298r   REG  8,192       83     0 100139241 /DB/data2/hadoop/hdfs/data/current/38743643/current/finalized/subdir204/subdir196/blk_15230354434 (deleted)
```

but the output is about non **root file system** path , so its not relevant

**so for summary**

On a rhel system, the root file-system is filling up by some unknown process.

It continues regardless of what files are moved or cleaned from the file system.

reference -

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/linux-filesystem-is-filling-despite-no-large-files-or-directories/
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

any other ideas how to know what else we can verify?

other idea - is to do reboot to server , but this is **LAST OPTION !**

Comment: Check `/var` filesystem

Comment: why to check /var , if our consuming is root file system ?

Comment: I do not see anywhere in the question your partitions and mountpoints.

Comment: There might be a large file that is opened early at boot time and then hidden by a mount point. Try `mount -o bind,rw / /mnt; du -kx /mnt | sort -rn | less`. You might find something like an accumulation of journal files in `/mnt/var/log/...`, created before your `/var` is mounted and hidden by the mounted `/var` filesystem. If you find nothing unusual, remove the bind mount with `umount /mnt`.